# Stateful loop with different types of breaks

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I am trying to convert the following stateful imperative code into Haskell.

```
while (true) {
  while (get()) {
    if (put1()) {
      failImmediately();
    }
  }
  if (put2()) {
    succeedImmediately();
  }
}
```

Both the `put1` and `put2` read a state of the system and modify it. `get` can for simplicity just read the state. `failImmediately` should break out of the endless-loop and present one type of result, `succeedImmediately` should also break out but present a different result.

What I tried to use was `State Env Result` where `Env` represented the state of environment and `Result` was something like `Either Failure Success` for some custom `Failure` and `Success`.

I struggle with the requirement that the whole resulting expression should collapse into the `Failure`/`Success` once one of them is produced (breaking the loop) and otherwise keep going.

One idea I had was use `Either Exit ()` where `data Exit = Success | Failure` and use `StateT` somehow to behave upon `Left` of the `Either` as if `Either` was the monad being chained, i.e. ignoring any subsequent actions.

I would really appreciate any inspiration or sample of haskell code that would achieve the same behaviour as the snippet above.

**Edit:** refined version moved to a separate question "[Stateful computation with different types of short-circuit (Maybe, Either)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398321/stateful-computation-with-different-types-of-short-circuit-maybe-either)".

Comment: You should look into [`EitherT (State Env Result)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-4.4.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html). Let me know if that hint is not enough and you need more details :)

Comment: I get the feeling this might be what I need except I don't have the slightest idea how to use it in this scenario :(. If you would be so kind to elaborate I would be ever so grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the kit from @chi's answer, just highlighting that you don't need the full power of `ContT`, the direct-short-circuiting semantics of [`EitherT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/either) is enough:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Either

data Result a = Failure | Success a

foo :: EitherT (Result Int) IO Int
foo = forever $ do
    whileM get $ do
        whenM put1 $ do
            left Failure
    whenM put2 $ do
        left $ Success 42

run :: (Monad m) => EitherT (Result a) m a -> m (Maybe a)
run act = do
    res <- runEitherT act
    return $ case res of
        Left Failure -> Nothing
        Left (Success x) -> Just x
        Right x -> Just x

-- whenM / whileM and get/put1/put2 as per @chi's answeer
```

Comment: I agree -- `ContT` is a bit overkill for this.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to solve my original question (when I replace IO with State). Couldn't it be even simpler considering the "edit" of my original post?

Comment: There's probably a `MonadPlus`-based solution to that... maybe worth a separate question (with the reduced question scope)

Answer (score 4):

An almost literal, non elegant but effective translation.

We exploit the `ContT` monad transformer to achieve the effect of 
"early return". I.e., we want to be able to break our loops at any point. This is achieved by using `callCC $ \exit -> ...` which roughly makes `exit` our magic function which let us escape from the inner blocks immediately.

```
import Control.Monad.Cont

action :: IO String
action = flip runContT return $ callCC $ \exit -> 
   forever $ do                   -- while (true)
      let loop = do
             r1 <- lift $ get     -- if (get())
             when r1 $ do
                r2 <- lift $ put1
                when r2 $         -- if (put1())
                   exit "failImmediately"
                loop              -- "repeat while"
      loop
      r3 <- lift $ put2
      when r3 $
         exit "succeedImmediately"

get :: IO Bool
get = readLn

put1 :: IO Bool
put1 = putStrLn "put1 here" >> readLn

put2 :: IO Bool
put2 = putStrLn "put2 here" >> readLn

main :: IO ()
main = action >>= putStrLn
```

We can also define some custom helpers to prettify the code:

```
action2 :: IO String
action2 = flip runContT return $ callCC $ \exit -> 
   forever $ do                -- while (true)
      whileM get $             -- while(get())
         whenM put1 $          -- if (put1())
            exit "failImmediately"
      whenM put2 $             -- if (put2())
         exit "succeedImmediately"

whenM :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m, Monad (t m)) => m Bool -> t m () -> t m ()
whenM condition a = do
   r <- lift condition
   when r a

whileM :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m, Monad (t m)) => m Bool -> t m () -> t m ()
whileM condition a = whenM condition (a >> whileM condition a)
```

Comment: Thank you, I hoped there was a way all the control-flow-like stuff (when) could be hidden in some abstraction (as maybe/either monads hide) also the two results are of different type, this example assumes both results to be IO String. I wish the whole thing to return either Success or Failure or never terminate.

Comment: If the results are of different types, you can use `Either A B` instead of `String` so that you can use that as the common type, after some `Left/Right` wrapping. You probably are already aware of that.

Comment: There might be some more elegant way to abstract everything using some clever looping combinator from some library. However, the code is pretty imperative and stateful: each line affects the state somehow. The imperative snippet is also quite simple -- I don't know if we can beat that in terms of clarity. Maybe someone else will come with a better solution.

Comment: @JakubDaniel I also realized you only need `State` instead of `IO`.