# Stateful computation with different types of short-circuit (Maybe, Either)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monad-transformers, state-monad, imperative-programming

I am trying to find the most elegant way of converting the following stateful imperative piece of code to pure functional representation (preferably in Haskell to use abstraction that its Monad implementation offers). However I am not yet good at combining different monads using transformers and the like. It seems to me, that analyzing other's takes on such tasks helps the best when learning how to do it myself. The imperative code:

```
while (true) {
  while (x = get()) { // Think of this as returning Maybe something
    put1(x) // may exit and present some failure representation
  }
  put2() // may exit and present some success representation
}
```

When `get` returns `Nothing` we need the execution to continue with `put2`, when `get` returns `Just x` we want the `x` to get passed to `put1` and short-circuit only if `put1` fails or loop otherwise. Basically `put1` and `put2` may terminate the whole thing or move to the following statement changing the underlying state somehow. `get` can either succeed and invoke `put1` and loop or fail and continue to `put2`.

My idea was something along:

```
forever $ do
  forever (get >>= put1)
  put2
```

And why I was looking for something like that is because `(get >>= put1)` could simply short-circuit whenever `get` has nothing to return or `put1` terminates. Similarly `put2` terminates the outer loop. However I am not sure how to mix the `State` with the necessary `Maybe` and/or `Either` to achieve this.

I think using transformers to combine `State` and the other monads is necessary and thus the code will most probably not be that succint. But I guess it as well might not be much worse.

Any suggestion how to achieve the translation elegantly is welcome. This differs from "[Stateful loop with different types of breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391924/stateful-loop-with-different-types-of-breaks)" in avoiding explicit control-flow using `if`, `when`, `while` and rather tries to encourage use of `Maybe`, `Either`, or some other handy `>>=` semantics. Also there is always a straight-forward way how to translate the code into a functional one, however it can hardly be considered elegant.

Comment: You need to mix failure "powers" in, too. This will look like `EitherT` or `MaybeT` and so you'll want to look into monad transformer stacks. Or! If you just want to explore, take a look at this monad: `data M e s a = M { runM :: e -> Either e (s, a) }` noting that it instantiates `MonadState s`.

Comment: Try to rewrite your original piece of code so that it doesn't use `exit()`. Can you how to do the functional equivalent of that now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stateful loop with different types of breaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391924/stateful-loop-with-different-types-of-breaks) - where is the difference?

Comment: it is a refined version of the original question, the difference lies in removing the control-flow and rather chaining the operations directly, allowing them to fail. Now the exchanged information is not simply `True`, `False` but `Maybe something` giving rise to a different chaining. The `put1` and `put2` do not seem to offer an easy way of being rewritten to not cause the main function to return. The answers to the original question did involve a lot of if-then-else like code, this is an attempt to use `>>=` of `Maybe` and `Either` instead.

Comment: @JakubDaniel: Ah, thanks for the edits!

Comment: When `put1` fails, do you want it to exit just the inner while loop or do you want it to exit both while loops?

Comment: Good question, I will change this in the original post. `put1` and `put2` are supposed to terminate the whole computation while `get` may produce `Nothing` which skips `put1` and breaks the inner loop.

Comment: I would recommend that you start by writing the whole thing out in Haskell by hand (without funny business like `exit` or especially `error`). That will give you a better sense of what the pretty abstractions you want actually need to support.

Comment: I don't understand, the `exit` is what makes the concept hard for me. Writing actions over `State` monad is something I already did. Now I realize that I have problem allowing some of the actions also behave exceptionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`EitherT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html) or [`ExceptT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html). It adds two ways to return to a transformer stack. The computation can either `return a` or `throwError e`. There are two differences between errors and returns. Errors are held on the `Left` and returns on the `Right`. When you `>>=` onto an error it short circuits.

```
newtype EitherT e m a = EitherT { runEitherT :: m (Either e a) }

return :: a -> EitherT e m a
return a = EitherT $ return (Right a)

throwError :: e -> EitherT e m a
throwError e = EitherT $ return (Left a)
```

We will also use the names `left = throwError` and `right = return`.

Errors on the `Left` don't continue, we will use them to represent exiting from a loop. We will use the type `EitherT r m ()` to represent a loop that either stops with a breaking result `Left r` or continues with a `Right ()`. This is almost exactly `forever`, except we unwrap the `EitherT` and get rid of the `Left` around the returned value.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Either

untilLeft :: Monad m => EitherT r m () -> m r
untilLeft = liftM (either id id) . runEitherT . forever
```

We'll come back to how to use these loops after fleshing out your example.

Since you want to see almost all of the logic disappear, we'll use `EitherT` for everything else too. The computation that gets data is either `Done` or returns the data.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

data Done = Done       deriving Show

-- Gets numbers for a while.
get1 :: EitherT Done (State Int) Int
get1 = do
    x <- lift get
    lift . put $ x + 1
    if x `mod` 3 == 0
    then left Done
    else right x
```

The first computation that puts data is either a `Failure` or returns.

```
data Failure = Failure deriving Show

put1 :: Int -> EitherT Failure (State Int) ()
put1 x = if x `mod` 16 == 0
         then left Failure
         else right ()
```

The second computation that puts data is either a `Success` or returns.

```
data Success = Success deriving Show

put2 :: EitherT Success (State Int) ()
put2 = do 
        x <- lift get
        if x `mod` 25 == 0
        then left Success
        else right ()
```

For your example, we will need to combine two or more computations that both stop exceptionally in different ways. We will represent this with two nested `EitherT`s.

```
EitherT o (EitherT i m) r
```

The outer `EitherT` is the one we are currently operating over. We can convert an `EitherT o m a` to an `EitherT o (EitherT i m) a` by adding an extra `EitherT` layer around every `m`<sup>†</sup>.

```
over :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => EitherT e m a -> EitherT e (t m) a
over = mapEitherT lift
```

The inner `EitherT` layer will be treated just like any other underlying monad in the transformer stack. We can `lift` an `EitherT i m a` to an `EitherT o (EitherT i m) a`

We can now build an overall computation that either succeeds or fails. Computations that would break the current loop are operated `over`. Computations that would break an outer loop are `lift`ed.

```
example :: EitherT Failure (State Int) Success
example =
    untilLeft $ do
        lift . untilLeft $ over get1 >>= lift . put1
        over put2
```

Overall `Failure` is `lift`ed twice into the innermost loop. This example is sufficiently interesting to see a few different results.

```
main = print . map (runState $ runEitherT example) $ [1..30]
```

---

<sup>†</sup>If `EitherT` had an [`MFunctor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#t:MFunctor) instance, `over` would just be `hoist lift`, which is a pattern that is used so often it deserves its own well thought out name. Incidentally, I use `EitherT` over `ExceptT` primarily because it has a less loaded name. Whichever one provides an `MFunctor` instance first will, for me, finally win out as the either monad transformer.

Comment: except ghc complains there is no Control.Monad.Trans.Either :(

Comment: @JakubDaniel, I think that's in the `either` package. Recent versions of `transformers` have `Control.Monad.Trans.Except`, which is pretty much the same.

Comment: If you use `ExceptT` instead of `EitherT` replace all of the `left`s with `throwE`, the `right`s with `return`, `runEitherT` with `runExceptT`, and `mapEitherT` with `mapExceptT`.

Comment: what version of `ghc` (I am assuming these modules come with it) do you have? Or is it the `transformers`? again what version should I have?

Comment: `transformers` and `either` are both packages you can install. running `cabal update` and then `cabal install either` will install both of them.

Answer (score 1):

> However I am not yet good at combining different monads using transformers and the like.

You do not really need to combine different monads with combinators, you only need to explicitly embed the Maybe monad in the State monad.  Once this is done, translating the snippet is straightforward, replacing loops by mutually recursive functions – the mutuality implements the branching conditions.

Let us write a solution this with OCaml and the [sparkling monad library Lemonade](https://github.com/michipili/lemonade) where the State monad is called Lemonade_Success.

So, I assume that the type representing errors returned by *put1* and *put2* is a string, representing a diagnostic message, and we instantiate the Success monad on the String type:

```
Success =
  Lemonade_Success.Make(String)
```

Now, the Success module represents monadic computation which can fail with a diagnostic.  See below for the complete signature of Success.  I write the translation of the snippet above, as a functor parametrised by your data, but of course, you can shortcut this and directly uses the implementation definition.  The data of your problem is described by a module Parameter having the signature P

```
module type P =
sig
    type t
    val get : unit -> t option
    val put1 : t -> unit Success.t
    val put2 : unit -> unit Success.t
end
```

A possible implementation of the snippet above would be

```
module M(Parameter:P) =
struct
    open Success.Infix

    let success_get () =
      match Parameter.get () with
        | Some(x) -> Success.return x
        | None -> Success.throw "Parameter.get"

    let rec innerloop () =
      Success.catch
        (success_get () >>= Parameter.put1 >>= innerloop)
        (Parameter.put2 >=> outerloop)
    and outerloop () =
      innerloop () >>= outerloop
end
```

The function get_success maps the Maybe monad to the Success monad, providing an ad-hoc error description.  This is because you need this ad-hoc error description that you will not be able to do this transformation using only abstract monad combinators – or, to phrase this, more pedantically, there is no canonical mapping from Maybe into State because these mappings are parametrised by an error description.

Once the success_get function is written, it is pretty straightforward to translate the branching conditions you described using mutually recursive functions and the Success.catch function, used to handle error conditions.

I leave you the implementation in Haskell as an exercise. :)

---

The complete signature of the Success module is

```
  module Success :
  sig
    type error = String.t
    type 'a outcome =
      | Success of 'a
      | Error of error
    type 'a t
    val bind : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t
    val return : 'a -> 'a t
    val apply : ('a -> 'b) t -> 'a t -> 'b t
    val join : 'a t t -> 'a t
    val map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a t -> 'b t
    val bind2 : 'a t -> 'b t -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c t) -> 'c t
    val bind3 : 'a t -> 'b t -> 'c t -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd t) -> 'd t
    val bind4 :
      'a t -> 'b t -> 'c t -> 'd t -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e t) -> 'e t
    val map2 : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a t -> 'b t -> 'c t
    val map3 : ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd) -> 'a t -> 'b t -> 'c t -> 'd t
    val map4 :
      ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e) -> 'a t -> 'b t -> 'c t -> 'd t -> 'e t
    val dist : 'a t list -> 'a list t
    val ignore : 'a t -> unit t
    val filter : ('a -> bool t) -> 'a t list -> 'a list t
    val only_if : bool -> unit t -> unit t
    val unless : bool -> unit t -> unit t
    module Infix :
      sig
        val ( <*> ) : ('a -> 'b) t -> 'a t -> 'b t
        val ( <$> ) : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a t -> 'b t
        val ( <* ) : 'a t -> 'b t -> 'a t
        val ( >* ) : 'a t -> 'b t -> 'b t
        val ( >>= ) : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t
        val ( >> ) : 'a t -> (unit -> 'b t) -> 'b t
        val ( >=> ) : ('a -> 'b t) -> ('b -> 'c t) -> 'a -> 'c t
        val ( <=< ) : ('b -> 'c t) -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'a -> 'c t
      end
    val throw : error -> 'a t
    val catch : 'a t -> (error -> 'a t) -> 'a t
    val run : 'a t -> 'a outcome
  end
```

In order to stay succinct, I removed some type annotations and hid the natural transformation `T` from the signature.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Honestly this is the first time I see OCaml so I cannot judge the answer. Hopefully I will decode it one day :)

Comment: If you can read Haskell you can probably not write OCaml but could be fine reading it. (I do not know Haskell but can more or less read it). The *signature* expresses type constraints (IIRC this is what `::` are for in Haskell).  The functor is maybe new to you because it is parametrised by a module, but you can more or less forget about it – just assume it is a macro of some sort. So now, there is only the `let rec… and …` which needs to be explained, and this is how mutually recursive functions are defined.

Comment: I am just starting to learn Haskell so I would not say I can read it (I get lost in the level of abstraction occasionally)

Comment: @JakubDaniel, note also that ML applies type constructors backwards, so `int list` is a list of ints. An `option` is a Maybe, with `Some` and `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit tricky, because you are asking an elegant way of something which is not really elegant. There is the [Control.Monad.Loops](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html) to write that type of loops. You'll probably need something like `whileJust'` or equivalent. Usually, we don't need to write `while` loops like that and plain old recursion is usually easiest.

I tried to find an example of when I would need this type of code and I came with the following example. I want to build a list of list of strings entered by the user. Each line correspond to an entry in the list. An empty line starts a new list, and two empty lines stops the loop.

Example

```
a
b
c

d
e

f
```

Will give

```
[ ["a", "b", "c"
, ["d", "e"]
, ["f"]
]
```

I would probably do the following in haskell

```
readMat :: IO [[String]]
readMat = reverse `fmap` go [[]]
    where go sss = do
                s <- getLine
                case s of
                    "" -> case sss of
                        []:sss' -> return sss' # the end
                        _ -> go ([]:sss)       # starts a new line
                    _ -> let (ss:ss') = sss
                          in go ((ss ++ [s]):ss')
```

Just plain recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This might overlap a bit with @Cirdec 's answer, but it also might help you gain a better perspective of what's going on.

The first thing to notice is that you really don't have doublely-nested loops. Without the exit statements, here is how you could write it as a simple loop:

```
example1 = forever $ do
  x <- getNext                -- get the next String
  if (isPrefixOf "break-" x)  -- do we break out of the "inner" loop?
    then put2 x
    else put1 x
  where
    put1 x = putStrLn $ "put1: " ++ x
    put2 x = putStrLn $ "put2: " ++ x
```

So now we just use the standard technique of using `runEitherT` for breaking out of a loop.

First some imports:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Either
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Data.List
```

and our result type and a convenience function:

```
data Result = Success String | Fail String deriving (Show)

exit = left
```

We then rewrite our loop lifting any IO actions and use `exit` when we want to break out of the loop:

```
example2 match =
  let loop = runEitherT $ forever $ do
        x <- getNext
        if isPrefixOf "break-" x
          then put2 x
          else put1 x
        where
          put1 "fail" = exit (Fail "fail encountered")
          put1 x      = liftIO $ putStrLn $ "put1: " ++ x

          put2 x      = if x == match
                          then exit (Success $ "found " ++ match)
                          else liftIO $ putStrLn $ "put2: " ++ x
  in loop
```

Here are some tests:

```
-- get next item from the state list:
getNext = do (x:xs) <- get; put xs; return x

test2a = evalStateT (example2 "break-foo") [ "a", "b", "fail" ]
test2b = evalStateT (example2 "break-foo") [ "a", "b", "break-foo", "c", "fail" ]
test2c = evalStateT (example2 "break-foo") [ "a", "b", "break-xxx", "c", "fail" ]
```

The output of these tests are:

```
ghci> test2a
put1: a
put1: b
Left (Fail "fail encountered")

ghci> test2b
put1: a
put1: b
Left (Success "found break-foo")

ghci> test2c
put1: a
put1: b
put2: break-xxx
put1: c
Left (Fail "fail encountered")
```

In this example the returned value of `runEitherT` will always be `Left r` where `r` is the `Result` value, so the code calling one of these examples might look like:

```
Left r <- test2a
case r of
  Success ... ->
  Fail    ... ->
```

Note that instead of a custom `Result` type you could just use `Either String String`:

```
type Result = Either String String
```

and use `Left` for `Fail` and `Right` for `Success`.

Comment: What about execution along the lines `(get >>= put1) >> put2`? I think that is not supported by your translation into a single loop. For every invocation of `put2` you seem to require to consume input with `get` without passing it to `put1`, but what if there is one entry in the input that has to trigger both `put1` and `put2`? i.e. there is input which lets you into the first loop and `put1` is executed, which modifies the state so that no other entry is discovered and `put2` is executed.

Comment: I think my answer is valid for the loop you have at the top of your question. Let me know if I am mistaken. If you have a different loop in mind let's discuss that in separate question.

Comment: Hmmm..  perhaps we were both confused for a moment. Here's the deal: I am assuming that `put1` can exit but if it does it exits both loops. This is one of the reasons why I asked that question in the comments. If `put1` can  exit just the inner loop then you can have `get` followed by `put1` followed by `put2`. So I think my answer is valid if `put1` either exits both loops or returns back to `get`.

Comment: But still, you introduce branching. My idea was that in my case the more important thing is that there is cycle that fetches data and reacts to them in some way. It does so while there are such data. And every time we are done with this we also perform some cleanup. the exact conditions can be hidden and abstracted away. What is important for me and for the readability in my case is the chaining of actions. If that makes sense.

Comment: You were right with the transformation, I got confused for a while.